# UIPageControl outer dots do not respond when selected (inner dots do)

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ibaction, uipagecontrol

For my iPad App, I have a main `ViewController` which contains two `UIScrollview`s and a `UIPageControl`. This works well except when I have more than the default three pages in the `UIPageControl`, in which case I set the number of pages manually in my VC using the call:

```
[self.pageControl setNumberOfPages:totalPages];
```

In such a case where the `pageControl` is set to say 10 pages (i.e. more than the default 3 pages) the dots outside of the 3 middle dots do not respond (i.e. the target action changePage function is not called when a user manually selects any of the dots outside the middle three)

see the picture shown:

Any help on how to resolve this would be most appreciated. Should I try `addTarget` to the 'changePage' function in code? (currently the target action is set in IB)

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: tried manually (i.e. in code) setting the target to changePage for action touchUpInside for the UIPageControl but it still does not work for the outer dots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this. The trick was to resize the UIPageControl in IB to the expected width (I did this in IB Size Inspector). I now see the changePage function getting called when I pick even the extreme end dots.